# How to Update Database Table after AjaxFileUpload ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

The file is uploading to the corresponding path but table (fileinfo) is not updating..
How to achieve the table updation after a file is being uploaded to the server

```
 protected void UploadComplete(Object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
 {
    string str = RadioButton1.Text;
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/" + str +"/") + e.FileName;
    AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog=example;user ID=sa;password=*******;");
    con.Open();        
    string command1 = "insert into fileinfo(fileid,filename,date1) values(@fileid,@filename,@date1)";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(command1, con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileid", "101");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", e.FileName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", DateTime.Now);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that your sql statement is working?

Comment: yea..the sql statement is working fine..as i have tested on a separate button click event..But on this UploadComplete after file uploads it is not executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retreive all the files stored in the folder str,  you can take array also to store, i have used the string jst to show you, that how you can get all the files from the folder

```
string getfile="";
foeach(string f in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/"+str+"/"))
{
  getfiles= getfiles + f + ",";
 }
```

Now You can store the getfiles in your database, I hope it will help you out